# How to strip EVERYTHING from a html string including texts but leave all <a> tags and their data intact using regex?

Tags: html, regex, string

Firstly I would like to say to the more experienced people than myself that it has to be done in regex. No access to a DOM parser due to weird situation.

So I have a full HTML/XHTML string and would like to strip everything from it except the links. Basically just the `<a>` tags are important. I need the tags to keep their information fully, so href, target, class, etc and it should work if its a self terminating tag or if it has a separate end tag. i.e. `<a />` or `<a></a>`

Thanks for any HELP guys!

Comment: That is nearly impossible. What is a *full HTML* string? What do you want to do with the string after the elements have been removed? Every browser has an HTML parser ;) In HTML, an end `</a>` tag is *required*.

Comment: im making a ajax call and getting a full html page back. I'm doing this inside a firefox extension so it makes it a lot harder. The idea is to get the html ajax response, dump it in a hidden field and then I have access to its elements.

Comment: @Daniel, my way so far includes string the script and img and head tags. but I rather strip everything and just have the link tags!
so far:
data = data.replace(/<head>(?:.|\n|\r)+?<\/head>/ig, "");
     data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*(?:\/>|>[\S\s]*?<\/script[^>]*>)/ig, "");
      doc.getElementById('123').innerHTML = data;

Answer (score 2):

Of course you have the possibility to parse HTML in a Firefox extension. Have a look at [*HTML to DOM*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM), especially the [second](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM#Using_a_hidden_iframe_element_to_parse_HTML_to_a_window%27s_DOM) and third way.

It might seem to be more complex, but it is less error prone than a regular expression.

As soon as you have a reference to the parsed content, all you have to do is to call `ref.getElementsByTagName('a')` and you are done.

Comment: @Amir: If you use jQuery anyway, then you are fine with `$(htmlStr)` I think. As I don't know the HTML I cannot tell you whether the selectors are correct or not.

Comment: Yes I would be ans it works if my code is part of a html page but smae code fails when working with a firefox extension. have a look at my last question before this one. I think that would make it more clear.

Comment: @Amir: Well using jQuery in Firefox extensions can be tricky (because there is a difference between the browsers DOM and a websites DOM). I suggest to load the data in an iframe as shown in the article I linked to and then use `querySelectorAll` to select the elements you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = subject.match(/<a[^<>]*?(?:\/>|>(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>)/ig);
```

gets you an array of all `<a>` tags in the HTML source (even self-closed tags which are illegal but which you specifically asked for). Is that sufficient?

**Explanation:**

```
<a         # Match <a
[^<>]*?    # Match any characters besides angle brackets, as few as possible
(?:        # Now either match
 />        # /> (self-closed tag)
|          # or 
 >         # a closing angle bracket
 (?:       # followed by...
  (?!</a>) # (if we're not at the closing tag)
  .        # any character
 )*        # any number of times
 </a>      # until the closing tag
)
```

Comment: I tried match, but i think its better if I get it as one string that I can dump in a innerHTML of a div. is that possible?

Comment: Not with regex. You can't match "all text outside of `a` tags" with JavaScript regex (no lookbehind assertions).

Comment: You can write something like `result = subject.replace(/(<a[^<>]*?(?:\/>|>(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>))|./g,'$1');` - but it's a little pointless, really - you can much more easily concatenate the matched links: `result = result.join('');`.

Comment: @kobi, This is great, except it also strips some links too. I cant see why but if it can be adjusted to keep all links then that would be great! possible?!

Comment: @Amir - there's a small issue with the above pattern - try replacing the `.` (in `# any character`) with `[\s\S]` - in JavaScript we don't have the `/s` flag, and `.` never matches newlines. It's possible you're losing such links (or links that have `>` in attributes ,but those are difficult). It should look like `result = subject.replace(/(<a[^<>]*?(?:\/>|>(?:(?!<\/a>)[\s\S])*<\/a>))|[^<]+/g,'$1');`. (I've also chnged the second `.` to `[^<]+` - that's just an optimization, it wouldn't solve real problems.

Answer (score 0):

the regex will look something like this

```
/\<\a.*[\/]{0,1}>(.*<\/\a>){0,1}/gm
```

Comment: will this work with the replace() function? something like htmlstring.replace(/\<\a.*>.*<\/\a>/gm,"");

Comment: this matches all <a attribute /> and <a attributes>value</a>, so you can replace them, yes.

Comment: sorry i think i said it wrong, i think this way ill be deleting all links instead of deleting everything else except links! am i confused?

Comment: well after you get the array of links you can paste them in a new string and so you drop everything else not needed and only keep the links